# React router routes in route not working . When I type /signUp, I can't get anything on the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I type /signUp, I can't get anything on the page, I couldn't solve this problem, can you help me?

```
    <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route  element={<AuthLayout />}>
  
        <Route path="signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
      
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I solved this problem. I just added outline from react-router-dom in AuthLayout Component and it is working right now.

Comment: Check if any error is coming?

Comment: Can you edit the post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see all that it is doing and rendering? Can you add the `AuthLayout` and `SignUp` component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your path you need a / in front `path="/signIn"`

Answer (score 0):

Why is AuthLayout wrapping SignIn, SignUp components?

Then AuthLayout page will be shown instead of SignIn page.

I think You should fix like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />} />
    <Route path="signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
    <Route path="signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```